# Convert object property and values to String

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, object

How can I convert a JavaScript object property and value into a string?

example:

```
{
  name: "mark",
  age: "20"
  status: "single"
}
```

expected output:

> name:mark AND age:20 AND status:single

Comment: With a loop? What have you tried? Do you want to output *all* properties, or specifically `name`, `age`, and `status` if present?

Comment: I want to output like _exactly_ the _expected output_ :). I tried several code but did not work.

Comment: Yes, and if the input was different, say, `{name:"mark",age:"20",status:"single",hobby:"bowling"}` what would the expected output be? Again, do you want *all* properties, or just specifically  `name`, `age`, and `status` if present?

Comment: the out put would be: `name:mark AND age:20 AND status:single AND hobby:bowling` . only if present :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, all variations on iterating through the object's properties. E.g.:

```js
function propsAsString(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) { return k + ":" + obj[k] }).join(" AND ")
}

console.log(propsAsString({ name: "mark", age: "20", status: "single" }))
console.log(propsAsString({ color: "red", shape: "square" }))
console.log(propsAsString({ name: "mary" }))
console.log(propsAsString({ })) // outputs empty string
```

Further reading:

- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Wow! thanks a lot @nnnnnn :) you save my day! very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution. Hope it helps!

```js
var someObject = {
        name: "mark",
        age: "20",
        status: "single"
    }
    var result = "";
    var counter = 0;
    for(var i in someObject){
        if(counter > 0){
         result += " AND ";
        }
        ++counter;
        result += i + ": "+someObject[i] + " ";
    }
    console.log(result);
```